# Where can I get Microsoft.DirectX.dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directx

I have no idea where to get it.
Is it just the Microsoft SDK?
And if yes, how can I add it to my project(Visual Studios 2010 C#)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The managed DirectX wrappers are obsolete and no longer included with the DirectX SDK.  The last version that had it was the February 2010 release.  You can still [download it](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10084).  Replacement is XNA.

Comment: An alternative to [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) is [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) (i've not used it, just giving an alternative).

Answer (score 0):

You can get it at [DirectX Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937781)

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the [Microsoft DirectX SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937788). This [Code Project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/mdx_tutorial1.aspx) goes over getting yourself up-and-running in Visual Studio.