# Where can I get the old managed directx files from?

Tags: c#, sdk, directx

An hour of google and 2 SDK downloads later! I downloaded the June and then following the link on a previous answer here on SO the Feb 2010 SDK (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731472/where-can-i-get-microsoft-directx-dll), but the dlls are nowhere to be found in either.

Comment: Upvotes because I think this is a good question to have in the archive with an answer so that people looking for it can find an answer. Might be worth editing the title to be even more specific to help searches find this answer.#

Answer (score 1):

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0 is where you will find them (fyi)

Comment: What about older versions, like 1.0.19xx?